# A coworker commited changes to the wrong branch and pushed to the remote repository. How can this be fixed?

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, tortoisehg

We are working on a project with a two-branch system (default/stable) and use a remote repository. A coworker has implemented a new feature on the wrong branch stable, and pushed the changes to the remote repository. The changes should have been made to the default branch.

Ideally, I would like to end up with the changes moved to the default branch, with no indication of the commit on the stable branch. Are we kinda screwed since it was already pushed?

I cloned the repo and tried to rollback the local copy, but that didn't have the effect I thought it would. I tried to use the rebase extension, but I don't see a way to move the commit to another branch. I tried the backout option, but that left history that I don't want.

I suppose I could do this manually by:

1. Making a copy of the changed files
2. Stripping the changeset from the local and remote copy
3. Updating to the default branch
4. Bringing the changed files back into the project
5. Committing the changes locally
6. Pushing the changes back to the remote repo

Is this the only way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the change is public, the only way to remove all trace is to strip the change for the public repo and all clones.  That could be impractical.

To undo the changes, you'll need to graft the changeset back to default, and backout the changeset from stable:

Example, current state:

[image: Current state of repository]

Commands:

```
hg update default
hg graft 3
hg update stable
hg backout 3
```

Result:

[image: Repository after commands]

Answer (score 1):

I'd first `graft` (see `hg help graft`) or `rebase --keep` (see `hg help rebase`, you may need to turn on the rebase extension) the changes from stable to default, then backout (see `hg help backout`) the changes from the stable branch. Once all the rebasing and backing out is done, push to the remote repositories your team uses.

Answer (score 1):

Since the errant change has already been pushed, and modifying the history on the remote repo is not an option, you have to add a changeset that completely reverses the effects of the errant change (`backout`). The history will still contain the errant commit and its inverse in `stable`, so anyone checking their repo against `stable` will be shown that there are updates they need to pull. There is no way to avoid this unless you strip the errant changeset.
As long as there were no secrets in the errant commit (and I don't imagine there would be any, if it belongs on `default`), maybe that's not a big deal.

**EDIT:** As Mark Tolonen points out, **the following will not work if changes have already been pushed (to a "publishing" repo).** So it's no use to the OP.

You can come pretty close to leaving no trace if you commit the backout changeset with `commit --amend`; it will meld the backout into the errant changeset, leaving an amended changeset with no file changes:

```
hg update -r oops
hg backout oops
<exit the editor without creating a commit message; commit is aborted>
hg commit --amend -m "Nothing to see here, folks"
```

The errant changeset will no longer be visible in the history:

```
% hg log -l 1
changeset:   4:969068ca0049
tag:         tip
summary:     Nothing to see here, folks
% hg diff -r tip
%
```

If I recall correctly, the original changeset will still be visible to users with a mercurial client so old that it does not support amended commits.

The above doesn't deal with moving the changeset to the correct place, but I trust you know how to do that (e.g., `graft`).

Comment: Oops, you're right! Somehow I'd missed that detail (I've never tried to amend when it was too late, it seems.)